# Struggling with fully changing a class component into a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting my journey into learning more about React and I wanted to try a project that searches a music API database. I came across some code that I wanted to utilize but it's was written in a class component and as the field is shifting into functional components I was trying to convert the code into a class component. Would someone be able to help?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Suggestions from 'components/Suggestions'

const { API_KEY } = process.env
const API_URL = 'http://api.musicgraph.com/api/v2/artist/suggest'

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  }

  getInfo = () => {
    axios.get(`${API_URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}&prefix=${this.state.query}&limit=7`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          results: data.data
        })
      })
  }

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      query: this.search.value
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
        if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
          this.getInfo()
        }
      } else if (!this.state.query) {
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          placeholder="Search for..."
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Suggestions results={this.state.results} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Search
```

Comment: Where in the conversion are you hitting issues? Can you post your initial attempt?

Comment: This looks pretty trivial (at least at first glance), fetch some stuff, display results. What part of it is giving you problems?

Comment: Can you provide your code attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a conversion of your component in functional component. I commented where i made changes :

```
const { API_KEY } = process.env;
const API_URL = 'http://api.musicgraph.com/api/v2/artist/suggest';

// declared as functional compoennt
const Search = () => {
  // State are used through Hooks now
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    query: '',
    results: [],
  });

  const getInfo = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${API_URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}&prefix=${state.query}&limit=7`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState, // Don't erase your previous state (unless it's needed)
          results: data.data,
        }));
      });
  };

  const handleInputChange = () => {
    setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        ...prevstate, // Same, don't lose your previous state
        query: this.search.value, // search is missing in your sample
      }),
      () => {
        // Remove 'this' everywhere, it's useless in functional component
        if (state.query && state.query.length > 1) {
          if (state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
            getInfo();
          }
        } else if (!state.query) {
        }
      }
    );
  };

  // No render anymore, only return
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        placeholder='Search for...'
        ref={(input) => (this.search = input)} // No idea where 'search' comes from, provide infos if you need help for this, a variable is missing i guess
        onChange={() => handleInputChange()} // Arrow function to handle the 'this' context
      />
      <Suggestions results={state.results} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Search;
```